# Need to check either selected or remove button displaying

Tags: cypress

There are two buttons in a page called Remove and selected.I need to check either one of the button's should be visible , beacuse sometimes selected won't be there.
Cy.get('remove button')
Cy.get('selected button')

I need to check whether either of the above elements should present. There will be case sometimes only remove will be available. So when I write above code  it's searching for selected button and throwing error.

Comment: Add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: Done . Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get either 'selected button' or (if not present) then 'remove button', you must specify the them in that order in a list

```js
cy.get('selected button',  'remove button')
```

But this is not official Cypress documentation. I think it can fail too many times because of page loading delays.

Here is the official pattern [Element existence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence)

```js
cy.get('body')
  .then(($body) => {
    if ($body.find('selected button').length) {
      cy.get('selected button').click()
    } else {
      cy.get('remove button').click()
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Writing the two selectors with comma denotes 'OR'. This means if `removeButtonSelector` is present consider that and move on, if not then go to `selectedButtonSelector`. For this to work, two things are necessary:

1. Make sure the page are loaded completely and all elements are loaded before this line of code is executed.
2. The other element should not exist on the DOM, otherwise everytime `removeButtonSelector` would be considered.

```js
cy.get('removeButtonSelector,selectedButtonSelector').should('be.visible')
```

Comment: I have given same as u suggested  but getting but never found it error.

Comment: I think you're missing a comma between the `removeButtonSelector` and `selectedBUttonSelector`. -> `removeButtonSelector,selectedButtonSelector`

Comment: A space does not denote `OR` with CSS selectors. It is a recursive child selector, so it will find the second selector underneath any children of and including the first selector.

Comment: Yes that is right. Was my mistake, updated the answer. Thanks for the heads up @agoff